# Webvimark module-user-management issue with custom User column

Tags: php, yii, webvimark

I cannot save value to Table for 3 custom fields of webvimark User class (not the Yii User class). I have added columns to User table, also added form fields to view form and checked for $model in webvimark UserController. In UserController, it has the custom fields from table but which save() is called, nothing in custom columns is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by making the following 2 changes in Webvimark User class:

1. Added properties at the start of the class:

   @property string $name

   @property string $phone

   @property integer $school_id
2. Added to rules():

   [['name','phone','school_id'], 'required'],